# HOW to fit Keras model regarding the error of train shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have reshaped my train data into a 3-D dataset that contains 1163 observation in 1002 time steps for 11 features. So I already have the train data and I made my model like below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape = (time_step,n_features), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mae','mse'])
model.fit(x=TRAIN,y=train_label,epochs=10)
```

but I got the error related to the shape of train data:
 `Error when checking input: expected lstm_5_input to have shape (1002, 11) but got array with shape (1163, 11)`
Do I need to reshape it again into another shape? Is not correct the data shape that I have `(Time steps, observation, number of features)`

Comment: *"1163 observation in 1002 time steps"* What do you mean exactly? You say the shape is 1163 observations x 11 feats., but pass to the model that there are 1002 observations...

Comment: @89f3a1c I mean in 1002 time steps, I have 1163 samples of 11 variables. means that, I have the data of 11 variables in 1163 spatial points in 1002 time steps.